# Right-to-left language not showing in Xcode preview from locale

Tags: xcode, swiftui, localization

In my Xcode preview in a SwiftUI view, I'm testing different locales like this:

```
ForEach(["ar-SA", "tr-TR"], id: \.self) { localIdentifier in
    ContentView()
        .environment(\.locale, Locale(identifier: localIdentifier))
        .previewDisplayName("Locale: \(localIdentifier)")
}
```

However, for Arabic in my example, it's showing left-to-right when it should be the opposite. It seems I have to manually do something like this:

```
ForEach(["ar-SA", "tr-TR"], id: \.self) { localIdentifier in
    content
        .environment(\.locale, Locale(identifier: localIdentifier))
        .modifier(if: localIdentifier.hasPrefix("ar-")) {
            $0.environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)
        }
        .previewDisplayName("Locale: \(localIdentifier)")
}
```

I thought the right-to-left should automatically be picked up from the locale. Is there something I'm missing so I don't have to explicitly set the `layoutDirection` and automatically read from the supplied locale?

Comment: Try adding the appropriate localization and localization files in your project. Seems like the problem is due to app initializing to default en_US locale in the absence of valid "ar" .lproj, and thus locale is left-to-right. Also, in Introducing SwiftUI: Building Your First App: 42:00 WWDC2019 they specify both the locale and direction, so maybe SwiftUI still cannot infer the direction manually? The UITraitCollection.current.layoutDirection is always leftToRight in my case on app's initialization (and hence LocaleDirection) but I only tested on a project without appropriate localization files.